# Powershell Invoke-WebRequest works but Python Requests does not

Tags: python, powershell, screen-scraping

This is about a weird situation where the Powershell Invoke-WebRequest works as intended and the Python Requests does not.

I am trying to scrape a ecommerce site using python. Part of the scraping is to test if an item can be added to cart. Using the Chrome Developer tools F12, I was able to extract the following Powershell scripts.

Step 1 - Request a customer session

```
$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$session.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"
$secPasswd=ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$myCreds=New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "username",$secPasswd
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://bck.hermes.com/customer-session?locale=de_de" `
-Proxy 'http://proxyaddress' `
-ProxyCredential $mycreds `
-WebSession $session `
-Headers @{
"sec-ch-ua"="`" Not A;Brand`";v=`"99`", `"Chromium`";v=`"99`", `"Google Chrome`";v=`"99`""
  "Accept"="application/json, text/plain, */*"
  "Cache-Control"="no-cache"
  "DNT"="1"
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile"="?0"
  "sec-ch-ua-platform"="`"Windows`""
  "Origin"="https://www.hermes.com"
  "Sec-Fetch-Site"="same-site"
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode"="cors"
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest"="empty"
  "Referer"="https://www.hermes.com/"
  "Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
  "Accept-Language"="en-US,en;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6,zh;q=0.5"
} | Select-Object -Expand RawContent
```

The response would give me a "ECOM_SESS" cookie along with a bunch others.

I would then pass the ECOM_SESS cookie to the next step.

Step 2 - add to cart

```
$session = New-Object Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WebRequestSession
$session.UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36"
$session.Cookies.Add((New-Object System.Net.Cookie("ECOM_SESS", "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX", "/", ".hermes.com")))
$secPasswd=ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$myCreds=New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "username",$secPasswd
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://bck.hermes.com/add-to-cart" `
-Proxy 'http://proxyaddress' `
-ProxyCredential $mycreds `
-Method "POST" `
-WebSession $session `
-Headers @{
"sec-ch-ua"="`" Not A;Brand`";v=`"99`", `"Chromium`";v=`"99`", `"Google Chrome`";v=`"99`""
  "Accept"="application/json, text/plain, */*"
  "DNT"="1"
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile"="?0"
  "sec-ch-ua-platform"="`"Windows`""
  "Origin"="https://www.hermes.com"
  "Sec-Fetch-Site"="same-site"
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode"="cors"
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest"="empty"
  "Referer"="https://www.hermes.com/"
  "Accept-Encoding"="gzip, deflate, br"
  "Accept-Language"="en-US,en;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6,zh;q=0.5"
} `
-ContentType "application/json" `
-Body "{`"locale`":`"de_de`",`"items`":[{`"category`":`"direct`",`"sku`":`"H079082CCAC`"}]}"
```

With the Powershell script above, the process works perfectly and I would get responses from each of the two steps. Note this is with a rotating IP proxy which refreshes the IP on each request to prevent bot detection.

However, when I tried to integrate this into my Python code, I would encounter the requirement of captcha upon Step 2, irrespective of the proxy server used.

Here is the relevant python code:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import bs4
import requests
from requests.cookies import RequestsCookieJar
import jsons

def main():
    url1= "https://bck.hermes.com/customer-session?locale=de_de"
    url2 = "https://bck.hermes.com/add-to-cart"
    proxies1 = {
        "http": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
    headers1 = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36',         
            'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"',
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
            'DNT': '1',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
            'Origin': 'https://www.hermes.com',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'document',
            'Referer': 'https://www.hermes.com/',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6,zh;q=0.5'
    }
    headers2 = {
            'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/99.0.4844.51 Safari/537.36',
            'sec-ch-ua': '" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"',
            'Accept': 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
            'DNT': '1',
            'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
            'sec-ch-ua-platform': '"Windows"',
            'Origin': 'https://www.hermes.com',
            'Sec-Fetch-Site': 'same-site',
            'Sec-Fetch-Mode': 'cors',
            'Sec-Fetch-Dest': 'empty',
            'Referer': 'https://www.hermes.com/',
            'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
            'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,ja;q=0.8,zh-CN;q=0.7,zh-TW;q=0.6,zh;q=0.5'
    }
    
    body2 = {"locale":"de_de","items":[{"category":"direct","sku":"H079082CCAC"}]}


    #Step 1

    f = requests.get(url1, headers=headers1,proxies=proxies1)
    print(f"1Response Body: {f.text}\n")
    ECOM_SESS = f.cookies['ECOM_SESS']
    cookieJar = RequestsCookieJar()
    cookieJar.set('ECOM_SESS', ECOM_SESS, domain='.hermes.com', path='/')

    #Step 2
    g = requests.post(url2, headers=headers2,cookies=cookieJar,proxies=proxies1,json=body2)
    print(f"2Response Body: {g.text}\n")

   

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running the Python code here, Step 1 would nicely give the intended response with the cookies needed to pass onto Step 2. However, Step 2 would always result in a captcha response.

I am just curious as to the difference between the Powershell Invoke-WebRequest method and the Python Requests method, as there has to be something fundamentally different for the former to avoid captcha completely and the latter to always get hit with captcha.

Would appreciate any thoughts and insights from you guys! Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to use Session object in python to carry over cookies and then update headers in POST? As a quick scan you seem to miss Content-Type in Python. Majority of your headers in both can almost certainly be removed as well. Perhaps test with a tool like Postman.

Comment: Also side note, you can use "-SessionVariable session" (no $ sign) for your initial Invoke without needing the 1st line. Any cookies the browser assigns will automatically be included in $session cookies after that.

Comment: Thanks QHarr for the tips. I tried the Session object and the result was quite similar to the Requests method. There has got to something I am missing here :(

Comment: Thanks Mike. That's a neat way of doing it that I was not aware. I am pretty new to writing scripts/code so good to learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure specifically what it is about requests that's triggering the bot protection on the site, but based on [this](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues/5003) you might have luck using:

```
requests.request("POST", url2, headers=headers2, cookies=cookieJar, proxies=proxies1, json=body2)
```

Alternatively you could try [urllib3](https://pypi.org/project/urllib3/) instead of Requests.

Here's your powershell script simplified too just as an excercise.

```
$secPasswd=ConvertTo-SecureString "password" -AsPlainText -Force
$myCreds=New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList "username",$secPasswd
$headers = @{
"sec-ch-ua"='" Not A;Brand";v="99", "Chromium";v="99", "Google Chrome";v="99"'
  "DNT"="1"
  "sec-ch-ua-mobile"="?0"
  "sec-ch-ua-platform"="`"Windows`""
  "Origin"="https://www.hermes.com"
  "Sec-Fetch-Site"="same-site"
  "Sec-Fetch-Mode"="cors"
  "Sec-Fetch-Dest"="empty"
  "Referer"="https://www.hermes.com/"
}
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://bck.hermes.com/customer-session?locale=de_de" `
-Proxy 'http://proxyaddress' `
-ProxyCredential $mycreds `
-SessionVariable session `
-Headers $headers
Invoke-WebRequest -UseBasicParsing -Uri "https://bck.hermes.com/add-to-cart" `
-Proxy 'http://proxyaddress' `
-ProxyCredential $mycreds `
-Method POST `
-WebSession $session `
-Headers $headers `
-ContentType "application/json" `
-Body "{`"locale`":`"de_de`",`"items`":[{`"category`":`"direct`",`"sku`":`"H079082CCAC`"}]}"
```

Comment: No luck using the requests.request method as you suggested. I am going to need to give urllib3 a try but may take me sometime to write it for the first time. I will let you know how it goes!

Comment: The shortened powershell script looks neat! no need to manually pass the cookie!

Comment: I have tried the urllib3 which also gives me the same result (of having bot detection). Absolutely strange behavour... what is so special about Powershell? There has got to be something hidden in the way Powershell Invoke-WebRequest does that Python is missing! Very frustrating :(

Comment: Could be worth trying with 'data' instead of 'json' in the python request field?

Comment: Otherwise I'd break out Fiddler - https://www.telerik.com/fiddler. Use it to inspect the requests from pwsh and python and see what's different.